# Frequency $\times $ Midpoint = What?

Tags: statistics

When finding the mean of grouped data, at some point you need to do:
Frequency $\times $ Midpoint = .....

Could someone tell me the name of the answer, does it have a name? Its labeled as `fx` in a lot of places, but I don't actually know what to call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would normally call it $ f \times m $, although if you want to give it a name you could say that it was an estimate of the total for that class interval (or group).

Sometimes I shorten it to just fm.

Comment: Ah ok, that sounds reasonable, thank :)